# Creating a new address in a blank wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I'm testing v0.21.1 on linux. I create a new blank wallet with: `bitcoin-cli createwallet "my_wallet" false true`

But when I try to create a new address with `bitcoin-cli getnewaddress` I get the following error:

```
error code: -4
error message:
Error: This wallet has no available keys
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a blank wallet which has no keys because of the third argument which is `true`.

> 3. blank                   (boolean, optional, default=false) Create a blank wallet. A blank wallet has no keys or HD seed. One can be set using sethdseed.

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/createwallet/

Comment: I do want to create a blank wallet with no pre-generated keys. Inside this brand new, empty wallet, I want to create new keys with `getnewaddress`. Perhaps `getnewaddress` is not the correct command to create a new address?

That command appears to create new addresses fine if I create a new wallet that is not blank.

Comment: 1. `getnewaddress` is the command to create new address. However you need keys to create address. 2. More information about HD wallets: https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/hd-wallets

Comment: Thank you @Prayank. I wonder if there is a way to create a new wallet without so many initial keys in it... the initial wallet file is relatively huge at over 1.5MB. Thanks again.

Comment: You can change that using the `-keypool=N` argument on the command line, or the `keypool=N` setting in the configuration file. Also, if you use a descriptor wallet instead of a legacy wallet, the file will generally be smaller on its own, even with the same number of addresses in it.